# Newtonsoft not hiding null values

Tags: json.net

Am I doing something wrong here?  When I run this code I still get the null values displayed.

```cs
var data = new Dictionary<string, string> {
    ["foo"] = "12",
    ["bar"] = null
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
});

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

The output of that (in LinqPad) is

```
{"foo":"12","bar":null}
```

Comment: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/792 "It applies to class properties not dictionaries" I think you would be better off filtering before serialization.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll filter them out.